# file output has two newline characters instead of one

Tags: c, file-io

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{ 
    FILE *p;char c[79];
    clrscr();
    p = fopen("file1.dat","w");
    printf("\nenter lines and enter end1 to end ");
    scanf("%s",c);
    if (strcmp(c,"end1") != 0)
       do
       {  
           fputc('\n',p);
           fputs(c,p);
           gets(c);
       } while(strcmp(c,"end1")!=0);

    fclose(p);
    p = fopen("file1.dat","r");
    printf("lines in file:\n");
    while(!feof(p))
    {
        fgets(c,80,p);
        printf("%s\n",c);
    }
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

My problem is that when I type (and write in the file)

```
hello
my name is abc
```

and then type end1 to terminate and when file contents are read and printed i get the output as

```
hello

my name is abc
```

Why are two newlines printed instead of 1 and how to solve this problem?

Comment: besides, you should really declare `char c[79]` as `char c[81]` :)

Comment: @anishsane sorry for not using the new standards but this is how i was taught

Comment: ^^ I would recommend you to use newer compilers, because people here don't assume that you are using older compilers & some issues may be specific to them (e.g. sizeof(int) = 2 vs 4 )... :-)

Comment: @anishsane thank you very much for the valuable input i was arguing with everyone that size of int is 2 not 4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the following regarding fgets()....

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
>   stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
>   EOF or a  newline.   If  a  newline  is       read, it is stored into
>   the buffer.  A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Given you are reading the file with fgets() then printing the file with printf( "%s\n", ... ) you are outputting two newlines.

Comment: besides, check if fputs appends a newline, just like puts does.

Comment: @K Scott Piel...my fault sorry for wasting all of ur time deleted the \n now works fine

Answer (score 1):

When you first call `scanf` the newline you type is left behind. You then put an explicit newline into the file, and call `gets` (this is **bad**), which picks up the first newline, then loops again to print another. So you get two.

If you call `getchar()` immediately after `scanf`, it will remove the extra newline (as long as you only type one word followed by enter). e.g.

```
scanf("%s",c);
getchar();             // discard newline
if (strcmp(c,"end1") != 0)
   do
   {  
       fputc('\n',p);  // you probably want to switch these two lines
       fputs(c,p);     //
       gets(c);
   } while(strcmp(c,"end1")!=0);
```

Comment: can you pls explain why using gets is bad?

Comment: @ragsvds - it's a huge security risk and can never be used safely, and it's been removed from the current C standard. You should use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @teppic-thank you for the information.could you suggest a way out of this problem?i tried the method as in the previous answer but i get the same output

Comment: @ragsvds - use `getchar()` as I suggest in this answer. It will remove the extra newline from the file.

Comment: @teppic-but i want to have several lines of input not characters

Comment: @teppic-thank you very much for your time i had made a small mistake in adding a \n in the last printf.solved it based on scott's answer..will try to remember and upvote ur answer wen i reach 15

Comment: @ragsvds - the \n in your printf will remove the newline from your screen output, but the file will still have one, unless you do this. The getchar() does have an effect, the compiler is being stupid :)

Comment: i wish there was a like button here

Answer (score 0):

the string sscanf'd includes a newline because that's what you typed in!

`c[strlen(c)] = '\0'` is a crude fix, replace the newline at the end with an extra null

Comment: Your code fragment is not replacing the newline... it's replacing the existing '\0' -- you meant c[strlen(c)-1] = '\0' -- in addition, this is problematic on Windows machines that use a CR/LF pair.